# Sharing VM over Airport

Tags: mac-osx, debian, virtual-machines, wifi

I've setup a Debian Virtual Machine as a development webserver on my desktop Mac OS X. I'm using shared networking for internet access and I've setup a static IP address. It's running Apache2 and SSL. Everything is working well.

However, I'm also sharing the internet over Airport to my Mac OS X notebook which I also want to access the VM. I figure its a sharing option and the firewall isn't enabled but so far I haven't had any luck trying to get it to work.

Comment: This should be on SuperUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to access your VM through the Internet, then you probably need to correctly configure your Airport to allow access (typically referred to as "port forwarding") - TCP Port 80 for HTTP.

Comment: I will test this as soon as I can get my Airport Utility to work properly!